# How do I get just the app id with PM2?

Tags: bash, pm2

Say I have an app named "fizzbuzz". I start it with `pm2 start index.js --name="fizzbuzz" --watch`. For automation purposes I'd like to just get the id of the app. I can grep it I guess but it seems like something that PM2 would have out of the box. I can't find it in the docs. For instance, I'd like to do this:

```
$ pm2 id --name="fizzbuzz"
3
```

Will I have to use grep and string manipulation in bash to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [link](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1143) out.

`process.env.pm_id` is the answer. I tested it and it's ok.

Comment: nice answer. I like it

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with node and grep. I am using the app name from package.json when I start the apps up. If I am in the root dir of the app, I can get that from package.json:

```
packageName=`node -e "console.log((require('./package.json')).name)"`
```

The I use pm2's mini-list feature, which outputs:

```
+--- alpha-beta-gamma 
pid : 4327
pm2 id : 2
status : online
```

Then I can grep it:

```
pm2 -m ls | grep "\-\- $packageName" -A 3 | grep "pm2 id" | grep -oP '\d+$'
```

Which returns:

```
2
```

PM2 is adding this in as a feature in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

Since you presumably can't add shell lines to pm2, you cannot use the $$ variable that provides the current process' id. There is another way without resorting to ps, grep, et al.

As long as your command is `pm2 start index.js --name="fizzbuzz" --watch`, you could do this:

```
pm2 start index.js --name="fizzbuzz" --watch &
fizz_pid=$!
```

The ampersand runs pm2 in the background. `fizz_pid=$!` writes the process id of the program last put into the background to the fizz_pid variable. (Caveat: adding a pipe `|` after the end of the pm2 command would likely break this.)

Comment: you do understand that `pm2 id` doesn't actually do anything, right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'd copied the wrong line from the OP. I updated the response.

Comment: That's alright, but how would I get the ID of an app I started last week?